# How do I cause global.asax to be triggered for a (now defunct) index.html (aka URL rewrite for poor)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, global-asax

I need to transparently replace **index.html** with **index.cshtml**. The problem is that I cannot push the change to the clients - they are going to continue using **index.html**.

Next, our IIS does not have the IIS URL Rewrite Extension and I cannot hope to make it happen.

Basically, I need to implement the rewrite myself. However, when **index.html** is requested my `global.asax` is not triggered, which makes sense.

So, my question is how do I trigger `global.asax` for **index.html**?

Now, I do have an answer that I have come up with, but since I am not an ASP.NET developer, it is likely a bad answer.

I will gladly accept answers as to how to rewrite the URLs using a different, more efficient and/or simpler approach. No HTTP redirects, though.

P.S.

The application contains no routing, no controllers and no views. It is essentially a static site (html+javascript). The only reason for cshtml is that certain resource paths must be computed at run-time on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is good enough for me. Basically, it is a rewrite for the index.html URL.

To recap:
First, I introduce a dummy handler for index.html in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <!-- The handler name is not an error !!! -->
    <add name="IndexHtmlHandler" verb="GET" path="index.html" type="Bogus.NonExisting.VirtualHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This is enough to trigger global.asax, which handles the actual rewrite:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context.Request.Path.EndsWith("index.html"))
    {
        context.RewritePath(context.Request.Path.Replace(".html", ".cshtml"));
    }
}
```